Is there a way to get physics to work with LuaLaTeX and unicode-math?
When I try to use the \vb* macro of the physics package with LuaLaTeX and the unicode-math package, not a single OpenType math font seems to support bold characters.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}  % Add \dv, \grad etc.
\newcommand\blurb{$\alpha \pi \lambda \vb*{\alpha\pi\lambda}$}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
%% Load 10 math fonts, plus two alternate/stylistic set variants
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[version=LM]
\setmathfont{Stix Math}[version=Stix]
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[version=XITS]
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[StylisticSet=1,version=XITS1]
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}[version=Stix2] % see http://stixfonts.org/
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}[version=Cambria]
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[version=Asana]
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[Alternate,version=AsanaAlt]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}[version=Pagella]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}[version=Termes]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}[version=DejaVu]
\setmathfont{Neo Euler}[version=Euler]
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}[version=Libertinus]

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.8}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
Latin Modern & \mathversion{LM}      \blurb \\
Stix         & \mathversion{Stix}    \blurb \\
XITS         & \mathversion{XITS}    \blurb \\
XITS, StySet1& \mathversion{XITS1}   \blurb \\
Stix Two     & \mathversion{Stix2}   \blurb \\
Cambria      & \mathversion{Cambria} \blurb \\
Asana        & \mathversion{Asana}   \blurb \\
Asana Alt    & \mathversion{AsanaAlt}\blurb \\
Pagella      & \mathversion{Pagella} \blurb \\
Termes       & \mathversion{Termes}  \blurb \\
DejaVu       & \mathversion{DejaVu}  \blurb \\[0.5ex]
Neo Euler    & \mathversion{Euler}   \blurb \\[0.5ex]
Libertinus Math& \mathversion{Libertinus} \blurb
\end{tabular}
\end{document}


could you explain the connection between your question and the comment? what does bold have to do with physics? your title suggests an incompatibility with luatex, but your question says nothing about what that incompatibility consists in.

and why do you think your example shows none of the fonts support bold?

@cfr In the blurb, I use the vb* macro, which is defined in physics to bold characters.

@cfr How should i be bolding in math on LuaLatex?  I'm disappointed because this used to work in regular latex.  Perhaps I should use symbf?

@cfr Okay, I think you solved it for me in your deleted answer: unicode-math is completely messing everything up (even without options).  Removing it seems to solve my problems.

no. I deleted it because it was completely wrong. forget you ever saw it. \symbf will work if you just load unicode-math and do nothing else. you are supposed to be able to get \mathversion working, but damned if I can see how right now.

The situation for bold is the same in latex as pdftex boldmath works if you have a bold math font, some do including the default latin modern, you can use FakeBokd to make a bold version of others or you can use the bold glyphs from the same font using symbf

I've taken the liberty of editing the title and first sentence of your posting to clarify what it is you're trying to achieve. I've also added the unicode-math tag. Feel free to revert.

And by the way, don’t use the physics package at all. It’s crap.

@Mico Thanks for being proactive!

@DavidCarlisle When you say "use the bold glyphs", is that different from "if you have a bold math font"?  Or does that mean the same thing?

@NeilG no unicode math fonts have bold (and script and fraktur) alphabets within the same font so \symbf{A} is not a font change it is a codepoint shift to U+1D400  which as you hopefully see here works even in this comment without any font change

@DavidCarlisle Thank you.  I've just read the unicode-math documentation introduction.  Should I be preferring commands like symbfit, etc.?  Is that the right way to bold math going forward?  Or should I be looking for a "bold math font" (wherever that could be found)?

@NeilG well that depends. My answeer set up bold fonts so the underlying \boldsymbol{...} works as before that means basically you get whatever you had, but bold so upright letters go to bold upright, italic go to bold italic, etc.  If you use \symbf or \symbfit you are explicitly selecting bold upright or bold italic so you can not just make a top level change you need to decide in each case which to use, ...

@NeilG so probably that is harder for a package like physics (ignoring that that package has other issues) as that really wants to say "make this bold" so for now I'd do what i suggested (even though you gave the tick to egreg:-) Probably at some point I will make \bm work with unicode-math or at least have some \just-make-it-bold-please{...} command that does the right thing in all cases, but there are some technical issues....

This is what physics does:
\DeclareDocumentCommand\vectorbold{ s m }{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\boldsymbol{#2}}{\mathbf{#2}}} % Vector bold [star for Greek and italic Roman]
\DeclareDocumentCommand\vb{}{\vectorbold} % Shorthand for \vectorbold

It's really hard to understand the intentions of the package author.1 According to ISO, vectors should be bold italic.2 So it's quite strange that the package offers as standard the wrong notation and the right one as a variant.
Anyway, neither \boldsymbol nor \mathbf will do the right thing with unicode-math.
If you want to reproduce what physics does with pdflatex also when unicode-math is used, you could do
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{physics}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\vectorbold}{sm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\symbfit{#2}}{\symbf{#2}}%
}
\RenewCommandCopy{\vb}{\vectorbold}

\begin{document}

$v\vb*{v}\vb{v}$

$\alpha \pi \lambda \vb*{\alpha\pi\lambda}$

\end{document}


Compare with
% compile with pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}

$v\vb*{v}\vb{v}$

$\alpha \pi \lambda \vb*{\alpha\pi\lambda}$

\end{document}


The simplest strategy is to forget about physics that's buggy and has an overall weird syntax for commands, besides taking wrong decisions in several cases.

Footnotes
1 \DeclareDocumentCommand is wrong here and throughout physics.sty.
2 Not that I endorse the notation prescribed by ISO.

The \boldsymbol command works fine with unicode-math, if you declare \setmathfont with version=bold. There just aren’t many OpenType math fonts with a bold version. By default \mathbf loads the bold text font, but unicode-math has a package option to make it a synonym for \symbf.

@Davislor But with \symbfit you can copy the exact Unicode point, which is not the case with \boldsymbol.

I agree that commands should use \symbfit where they can and \boldsymbol where they have to. I suspect the physics package does things that way because LaTeX doesn’t define any bold-italic-math alphabet in the kernel. (The isomath package fills in this gap.)

Excellent answer, thank you!  Could you explain what this does? \RenewDocumentCommand{\vectorbold}{sm}{%   \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\symbfit{#2}}{\symbf{#2}}% }?  I'd like to ditch the bold-upright and provide a definition of vb now that you've convinced me to ditch physics.  Also, is there a way to have a single vb macro that works with Latin and Greek characters?

@NeilG I'm just throwing away physics' definition and replacing with a new one; since the package makes \vb as an alias to \vectorbold, I do the same. My advice is to throw away physics altogether.

Thanks, I see that.  I'm going with this then: \RenewDocumentCommand{\vectorbold}{m}{\symbfit{#1}} since as you say the * seems counterproductive.  Suppose I don't use unicode-math or physics.  Then how should I define it?

What is wrong with \DeclareDocumentCommand? Do you want \New... instead?

@Gaussler Definitely.

The Physical Review (which is the most prestigious physics-only journal) mandates upright bold for three-vectors, and I would say the vast majority of physicists would prefer to be in the positionof writing something following that style guide than the ISO standard ;) https://cdn.journals.aps.org/files/styleguide-pr.pdf

@llama The rules imposed by ISO are contradictory. For instance, they fail to understand that matrices are a special kind of tensors, but impose that symbols for tensors are typeset differently from matrices. Not to mention the ridiculous justification why physical constants should be in italics (they don't have a fixed value, according to them). And my opinion is that nobody should be forced to follow such rules, until they're made avaliable for free.

You wrote

When I try to use the \vb* macro of the physics package with LuaLaTeX and the unicode-math package, not a single OpenType math font seems to support bold characters.

and also commented

unicode-math is completely messing everything up

Not really. Just replace \vb*{\alpha\pi\lambda} with \symbf{\alpha\pi\lambda}.
Two additional observations:

What's so important about using \vb*?

I had to change \setmathfont{Neo Euler} to \setmathfont{Euler Math} to get your code to work without a hitch.



\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}  % Add \dv, \grad etc.
\newcommand\blurb{$\alpha\pi\lambda\  \symbf{\alpha\pi\lambda}$}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
%% Load 10 math fonts, plus two alternate/stylistic set variants
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[version=LM]
\setmathfont{Stix Math}[version=Stix]
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[version=XITS]
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[StylisticSet=1,version=XITS1]
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}[version=Stix2]
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}[version=Cambria]
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[version=Asana]
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[Alternate,version=AsanaAlt]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}[version=Pagella]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}[version=Termes]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}[version=DejaVu]
\setmathfont{Euler Math}[version=Euler]
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}[version=Libertinus]

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Latin Modern   & \mathversion{LM}      \blurb \\
Stix           & \mathversion{Stix}    \blurb \\
XITS           & \mathversion{XITS}    \blurb \\
XITS, StySet1  & \mathversion{XITS1}   \blurb \\
Stix Two       & \mathversion{Stix2}   \blurb \\
Cambria        & \mathversion{Cambria} \blurb \\
Asana          & \mathversion{Asana}   \blurb \\
Asana Alt      & \mathversion{AsanaAlt}\blurb \\
Pagella        & \mathversion{Pagella} \blurb \\
Termes         & \mathversion{Termes}  \blurb \\
DejaVu         & \mathversion{DejaVu}  \blurb \\
Euler Math     & \mathversion{Euler}   \blurb \\
Libertinus Math& \mathversion{Libertinus} \blurb
\end{tabular}
\end{document}


@Gaussler - Thanks for the edit.

Neo Euler isn’t part of the CTAN distribution and would need to be downloaded from its GitHub page.

@Davislor - Is it correct to say that Euler Math is based (closely, presumably) on Neo Euler?

Yes, Euler Math is a fork of Neo Euler.

Your issue is unrelated to luatex or the physics package, you would see the same in classic TeX.
\boldsymbol justt locally uses \boldmath to select \mathversion{bold} so this works well when you just have two math versions, normal and bold but if you define multiple math versions you need to also define multiple bold versions and arrange to switch them.
Here I just locally disable \mathversion  so that \mathversion{anything} selects the bold version of the math version just selected, as this saves redefining the underlying commands.
I also just used FakeBold, although some of tehse do have a real bold math font that you coudl use, and a value of 3 is a bit excessive but makes it clear when debugging.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\blurb{$\alpha \pi \lambda \boldsymbol{\alpha\pi\lambda}$}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
%% Load 10 math fonts, plus two alternate/stylistic set variants
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[version=LM]
%\setmathfont{Stix Math}[version=Stix]
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[version=XITS]
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[StylisticSet=1,version=XITS1]
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[version=Stix2] % see http://stixfonts.org/
%\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}[version=Stix2] % see http://stixfonts.org/
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}[version=Cambria]
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[version=Asana]
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[Alternate,version=AsanaAlt]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}[version=Pagella]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}[version=Termes]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}[version=DejaVu]
%\setmathfont{Neo Euler}[version=Euler]
\setmathfont{Euler Math}[version=Euler]
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}[version=Libertinus]

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[version=boldLM,FakeBold=3]
%\setmathfont{Stix Math}[version=Stix]
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[version=boldXITS,FakeBold=3]
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[StylisticSet=1,version=boldXITS1,FakeBold=3]
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[version=boldStix2,FakeBold=3] % see http://stixfonts.org/
%\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}[version=Stix2] % see http://stixfonts.org/
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}[version=boldCambria,FakeBold=3]
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[version=boldAsana,FakeBold=3]
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[Alternate,version=boldAsanaAlt,FakeBold=3]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}[version=boldPagella,FakeBold=3]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}[version=boldTermes,FakeBold=3]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}[version=boldDejaVu,FakeBold=3]
%\setmathfont{Neo Euler}[version=Euler]
\setmathfont{Euler Math}[version=boldEuler,FakeBold=3]
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}[version=boldLibertinus,FakeBold=3]

\let\oldmathversion\mathversion
\def\bversion#1{\def\mathversion##1{\oldmathversion{bold#1}}}
\begin{document}


\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.8}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
Latin Modern & \mathversion{LM}\bversion{LM}      \blurb \\
%Stix         & \mathversion{Stix}\bversion{Stix}    \blurb \\
XITS         & \mathversion{XITS}\bversion{XITS}    \blurb \\
XITS, StySet1& \mathversion{XITS1}\bversion{XITS1}   \blurb \\
Stix Two     & \mathversion{Stix2}\bversion{Stix2}   \blurb \\
Cambria      & \mathversion{Cambria}\bversion{Cambria} \blurb \\
Asana        & \mathversion{Asana}\bversion{Asana}   \blurb \\
Asana Alt    & \mathversion{AsanaAlt}\bversion{AsanaAlt}\blurb \\
Pagella      & \mathversion{Pagella}\bversion{Pagella} \blurb \\
Termes       & \mathversion{Termes}\bversion{Termes}  \blurb \\
DejaVu       & \mathversion{DejaVu}\bversion{DejaVu}  \blurb \\[0.5ex]
Neo Euler    & \mathversion{Euler}\bversion{Euler}   \blurb \\[0.5ex]
Libertinus Math& \mathversion{Libertinus}\bversion{Libertinus} \blurb
\end{tabular}
\end{document}


In a normal document, even with unicode-math  you would just use
\setmathfont{...} to set up the normal version and \setmathfont[version=bold]{...} to set up bold math.

Also as Mico shows For these particular characters OpenType math fonts have the bold glyphs in the same font so locally redefining \boldsymbol to be \symbfit would also work.

Would you mind giving an example of selecting the appropriate bold math font rather than doing the less pretty "fake bold"?

@NeilG $ find . | grep -i bold | grep -i math ./public/concmath-otf/Concrete-Math-Bold.otf ./public/erewhon-math/Erewhon-Math-Bold.otf ./public/kpfonts-otf/KpMath-Bold.otf ./public/kpfonts-otf/KpMath-SansBold.otf ./public/kpfonts-otf/KpMath-Semibold.otf ./public/lete-sans-math/LeteSansMath-Bold.otf ./public/newcomputermodern/NewCMMath-Bold.otf ./public/xcharter-math/XCharter-Math-Bold.otf ./public/xits/XITSMath-Bold.otf

@NeilG  so of the math fonts you list, only XITS, but you can replace \setmathfont{XITS Math}[version=boldXITS,FakeBold=3] by \setmathfont{XITSMath-Bold.otf}[version=boldXITS] to use the supplied bold font rather than automatically genearting a bold version of the normal

Got it, so it appears that being able to find a bold math font is quite rare?  Considering that fake-bold isn't that pretty, then unicode-math's symbfit seems like the most visually-appealing solution?  While I agree that yours is more user-friendly (in that it just "makes the argument bold").

@NeilG yes fake bold is less horrible if you use something like 1.5 rather thah 3, but 3 gets noticed:-) as for what to do in general yes it depends, \symbf is a designed visually compatible bold but (a) only for latin and greek, so if you have cyrillic or a symbol such as + you are out of luck and get no bold, choosing a bold math font gives better results, if you can find one...  As i say defining a \ignore-technical-issues-and-make-this-bold command is explicitly on the roadmap (we have a github issue somewhere) but it's not entirely clear what it should do

The physics package uses the \boldsymbol command, I suspect because there is no bold-italic-math command in the LaTeX kernel.  This sets \mathversion{bold}.  You changed around the math versions but didn’t ever set that one up.
It also uses \mathbf in some places.  By default, unicode-math sets \mathbf as the bold text font, for words in math mode, and makes the Unicode bold upright mathematical symbols available through \symbfup.  You can override this, however, with the package option mathbf=sym.  There are similar package options for \mathrm, \mathup, \mathit, \mathsf and \mathtt.
A MWE that sets up a bold math font and \mathbf:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}  % Add \dv, \grad etc.
\newcommand\blurb{$\alpha \pi \lambda \vb*{\alpha\pi\lambda}$}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO,mathbf=sym]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}

\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book.otf}
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Bold.otf}[version=bold]

\begin{document}
\blurb
\end{document}


If you genuinely need to change between different math fonts in the same document, such as between sans-serif and serif, you want to define math fonts for version=sans and possibly version=boldsans.  Use the alphabets like \symsfup and \symbfit whenever you can, but it is also possible to define new commands analogous to \boldsymbol, e.g.:
%% Based on the definition of \boldsymbol from amsbsy.sty"
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\sanssymbol}[1]{%
  \begingroup%
  \let\@nomath\@gobble \mathversion{sans}%
  \math@atom{#1}{%
  \mathchoice%
    {\hbox{$\m@th\displaystyle#1$}}%
    {\hbox{$\m@th\textstyle#1$}}%
    {\hbox{$\m@th\scriptstyle#1$}}%
    {\hbox{$\m@th\scriptscriptstyle#1$}}}%
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

If you’re reconsidering whether you want to use physics at all, see @egreg’s answer.  (I respectfully disagree with his suggestion to use low-level formatting commands in the body of your document rather than high-level semantic markup, especially if you might have to copy-and-paste an equation into a document for legacy TeX or change to your publisher’s house style.)
